# Uninstalling extension in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-2017, vspackage, vsixmanifest

I've been testing our extension in VS2017 RC and it installs perfectly but when I try to uninstall it I find that it is impossible.

It says that the extension will be uninstalled when all Visual Studio windows are closed but this does not work. When I try the same extension in other versions of Visual Studio such as 2013, there is a "Restart Now" button that appears after invoking the uninstall.

Is this a known issue or is there something wrong with my extension?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has changed with Visual Studio 2017. Close all instances of Visual Studio and the vsix installer should pop-up and ask you to modify the current installation for your extension and perform the uninstall.

A few changes to your extension are required:

- http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2016/11/16/visual-studio-2017-rc-announced-extensions-need-some-changes/

Comment: Thanks. I've not seen that dialog come up but I have not made any VS2017 specific changes to the extension. I'll check that link.